# ¿Como puedo separar una cadena en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero encriptar unas contraseñas que ingreso en un editText pero para ello necesito separar las contraseñas por carac

Answer (score 0):

Primero tendrías que guardar el texto en un String y luego recorrerlo por "substrings" de la siguiente manera:

*Supongamos que tu editText contenga la palabra "Contraseña"
entonces ejecutamos el siguiente código:*

```
String pass = tuEditText.getText();
for(int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++){
        System.out.println(pass.substring(0+i,i+1));
   }
```

*Y la salida será:*

```
//Salida
C
o
n
t
r
a
s
e
ñ
a
```

Con la instrucción "substring" puedes obtener una letra de tu String y ahora ya con la cadena separada tú puedes agregar cada letra a una variable o lo que tú desees hacer para encriptarla.

Espero que te sirva.